# Aplication of Riesz representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

For the purpose of practice I took on the following problem about the Riesz representation theorem which asks me to find the unique element whose existence the representation theorem ensures.

Let $H = L^2(0,1)$ and for $u \in H$ let $F$ be the functional

$$ F(u) := \int\limits_{0}^{1/2} u(t)\, dt $$

Show that $F$ is continuous and linear on $H$, calculate its operator norm and find the unique element $f \in L^2(0,1)$ which represents $F$ by Riesz representation theorem

$$ \langle u, f \rangle = \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(t) u(t)\, dt \quad \forall u \in L^2(0,1)$$

The first part I think I solved. The linearity of the functional is quite clear due to the Lebesgue integral properties, i.e.

$$F(\alpha u_1 + u_2) = \int\limits_{0}^{1/2} \alpha u_1 + u_2 dt = \alpha F(u_1) + F(u_2) $$

Also, it's continuous since

$$F(u) = \int\limits_{0}^{1/2} u(t)\, dt \leq \int\limits_{0}^{1} \lvert u \rvert dt \leq \int\limits_{0}^{1} \lvert u(t)\rvert^2\, dt$$

and hence

$$F(u) \leq \Vert u \Vert_{L^{2}(0,1)}$$

What I struggle with is the operator norm and to actually find $f \in L^2(0,1)$. I read that the operator norm of a functional

$$F_g(u) = \int\limits_{\Omega} ug \, dt $$

is given by $\Vert F\Vert  = \int\limits_{\Omega} \lvert g\rvert\, dt$. But what is it in my case and how do I find the unique element $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riesz representation $f$ of $F$ should obey
$$
 F(u) = \int fu\,\mathrm dt.
$$

Thus it can be seen that $f=\chi_{(0,\frac12)}$ has to be the representant of $F$.

The operator norm for functionals on $L^2(0,1)$ obeys $\| F\|^2 = \int |f|^2 \,\mathrm dt$.
This is easy to calculate for the function $f$ above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With regard to the operator norm, is it then just the squared indicator function over (0, 1), i.e. the squared measure of the unit interval?

Comment: note that $f$ is the indicator function over $(0,\frac12)$, not $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks! That helped!